# Correct British English Usage of Words

Tags: british-english, spelling

There are multiple words that are spelt differently in British English and American English. Which of these spellings is correct for **British English**?

- donut / doughnut
- aluminum / aluminium
- grey / gray
- meter / metre
- cozy / cosy
- program / programme
- mustache / moustache
- sulphur / sulfur
- fulfil / fulfill
- jewelry / jewellry
- defence / defense

###### Side note: is it "cotton candy" or "candy floss"?

Comment: Any decent dictionary will answer all your questions. Why should we do the work for you?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

- doughnut
- aluminium
- grey
- metre
- cosy
- program
- moustache
- sulphur
- fulfill
- jewelry
- defence

Comment: No. In BrE we use programme. We reserve program for a set of instructions for a digital computer.

Comment: No, the standard BrE spelling is _fulfil_, not _fulfill_. The GloWbE corpus has fulfill:fulfil 4419:611 US, 1783:462 CA, but 1965:3517 GB, 550:877 IE, 791:1094 AU, and 495:727 NZ.

Comment: Ditto _jewellery_, which shows a very similar pattern vs _jewelry_ as _fulfil_ vs _fulfil_.

Comment: IN other words, this answer is wrong in several places.

Comment: There are seven towns in America named for element 16: in Louisiana, Oklahoma, Nevada, Texas, Wyoming, Arkansas, and South Dakota. All of them named Sulphur.